# The HTML $.get pulls does not include the divs that I create via jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve a (dynamic) link on Page2 from Page1. On Page1 I have this script:

```
$.get("./page2", function(res) {
   console.log(res);       
   var fetchedInfo = ($(res).find("span#link a").attr("href"));
   console.log(fetchedInfo);
});
```

`console.log` in the above code returns the HTML of Page2 but omits the `span` entirely from the HTML. The only reason I can figure this is happening is because for Page2 I have JS that creates the span.

`$('.object1').append('<span id="link"><a href="   ' + linkURL +  '   ">' + headlineText +  '</a></span>');`

Since it's not showing up in the `get` HTML, is it possible for me to get the `span a href` on Page2 from Page 1?

Comment: Since you have access to both files, can't you just hard code in a class/ID or the span in page2? If the span is special you could always give the `<a` its own class hardcoded like `<a class='urllink'`or give it an id, that way in your jquery you can easily reference that link.

Comment: I'll try a hardcoding solution. It's a weird situation because it's a WordPress template made of mostly PHP that spits out the HTML and I have a lot of trouble editing it in non-workaround ways.

Comment: "*page2 has JS that creates the span*" - `$.get` gets the HTML - it doesn't run any random, nefarious js that might be on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems the only way to do it is to have hardcoded HTML that you want to pull. Doing that solved the problem.